# Logging in spotify with ionic 2

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2, spotify

I am creating an application in ionic 2

I am building a screen to login to the web api of spotify

In spotify documentation it is required to add a Redirect URI

How do I get these Redirect URIs when the app is already installed on the mobile?

**Note: I'm just using javascript without backend(node, c#, java)**

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/

type:Implicit Grant Flow
[image]

https://developer.spotify.com/my-applications/
app
[image]

Comment: did you try with adding `cordova-plugin-whitelist` plugin to your app?

Comment: After the login I need to return to the app, how would this plugin help me?

Comment: did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: You could use an URI Scheme (eg. yourapp://callback) and intercept it in your app. The plugin [cordova-spotify](https://github.com/Festify/cordova-spotify) is using this method in order to authenticate the user.